# Is there a module that shows when you last updated or modified an installed module?

Tags: 7

From time to time I update my modules and I would like to see when they were last updated. Is there such a module that adds this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, no module, but `ls -l` in your module directory should give you the dates of last updates.

Btw. it is trivial to create a module that does this. Just throw a module wrapper around something like:

```
$modules = '/www/sites/all/modules/'; // Path to your module directory.
$output = shell_exec('ls -l ' . $modules);
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

Comment: actually this doesnt work in my case as i cloned a copy of my site to another server and all the dates on the files get changed.

Comment: I didn't account for that, but now i know to account for that.